# How Can I Incorporate Profiles in CiviEvent Backend?

Tags: civievent, profile

I am trying to work out how to update custom profile information from the civievent back-end, however I can not get a profile to appear for updating.

Scenario: We are running an event where delegates can either sign-up via our website, or via a paper form. We need to collect specific information for the event such as access and diet requirements. An organiser will be responsible for inputting details from any paper forms received.

---

I have a profile set up with the additional information which works as expected when used for an online booking and exports without an issue. I have enabled for this profile:

- Used for Standalone Form or Directory, CiviEvent_Additional, Search Views
- Type Associate, Contact, ParticipantEventName::

So, I would have expected this to allow me to input this information either:

- when I go to civicrm/participant/add?reset=1&action=add&context=standalone&eid=XX but it does not appear there
- or when I search for participants, highlight them and try to *Update via Batch Profile* but it does not appear there either

*Of Note: the profile used in the same event used for CiviEvent does not appear either*

I did think that I might have to import the data via a CSV, but there must be an easier way that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't a direct answer to the Q but may be what you want. At the top of Events registration page you should be able to see eg Welcome Joe Doe. (Not Joe Doe, or want to register a different person?) (eg at [demo site](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=3))

If you click on that option you should then get to a url with cid=0 such as http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/register?cid=0&reset=1&id=3 and this should allow a back-end user to register someone using the same Profiles etc that anyone would use via the front end.

Is that what you need?

Comment: Hi @petednz-fusion - I had thought of doing that and it may be that I will end up using that method. I have to be mindful that the person doing this may only have an administrative IT competence; telling them to set it up as a Pay Later then immediately go in and change the status to Registered is a way forward.

Comment: okay - if it proves to be a workable solution, if not the absolute ideal answer, perhaps you could plus-1 it so its use to others is noted, and 'accept' if you feel so inclined